# How do I parse the output of msdeploy and fail a TeamCity build if there are errors?

Tags: teamcity, msdeploy

I'm using msdeploy.exe run from TeamCity for deploying ASP.Net projects to staging servers but if suffers severely from always returning a 0 status on exit, even when it raises several errors. This means that a bad deploy does not fail and all looks OK.

So I need to parse the output and have that raise an error, is there an easy way to do this? Alternatively, is there a hard way to do this?

You can see from the TeamCity build log below what is going on (errors, but carries on due to 0 exit status).

```
[17:32:31]: Skip copying Global.asax to  obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Global.asax, File  obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Global.asax is up to date
[17:32:31]: C:\Program  Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1845,5):  error : Copying file Web.Debug.config to  obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Web.Debug.config failed. Could not find  file 'Web.Debug.config'.  [C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj]
[17:32:31]: Done Building Project  "C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj" (Package  target(s)) -- FAILED.
[17:32:31]: Build FAILED.
[17:32:31]: "C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj" (Package  target) (1) ->
[17:32:31]: (ValidateGlobalPackageSetting target)  ->
[17:32:31]: C:\Program  Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(817,5):  error : '..\Package\WebApp.zip' exists as a file. You can't package as  an archive directory to be the same path as an existing file. Please  delete the file before packaging. Alternative,you can call msbuild with  /t:CleanWebsitesPackage target to remove it.  [C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj]
[17:32:31]: "C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj" (Package  target) (1) ->
[17:32:31]: (CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage  target) ->
[17:32:31]: C:\Program  Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1845,5):  error : Copying file Web.Debug.config to  obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Web.Debug.config failed. Could not find  file 'Web.Debug.config'.  [C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9\webapp\WebApp.csproj]
[17:32:31]: 0 Warning(s)
[17:32:31]: 2 Error(s)
[17:32:31]: Time Elapsed 00:00:00.87
[17:32:31]: C:\BuildAgent\work\f3548ee02a6397b9>"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft  Web Deploy"\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:Package=Package\WebApp.zip  -dest:auto -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"=MyWebName
[17:32:32]: Info: Updating setAcl (MyWebName).
[17:32:32]: Info: Updating setAcl (MyWebName).
[17:32:32]: Info: Updating setAcl  (MyWebName/App_Data).
[17:32:32]: Total changes: 3 (0 added, 0 deleted,  3 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
[17:32:32]: Process exited with code 0
[17:32:32]: Build finished
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TeamCity 7 has a Build Failures feature:

- Edit Settings on your build configuration
- Go to the Build Failure Conditions tab (number 4)
- Click 'Add build failure condition'
- Select the 'Fail build on specific text in build log' type
- I used the string "EXEC : error count:" to catch MSDeploy errors, it works well
- The Test button opens a handy dialog where you can test your failure condition on a previous build log that you know should have failed
- Save

In my configuration I'm invoking msdeploy.exe directly from MSBuild, I think that's why my error text is different to yours.

Pretty cool, loving JetBrains for this.

Comment: This is a good solution, one which I completely overlooked. It works well. Just for reference, I used the regexp text option with a value of "Error count: [1-999]" which seems to work alright for MSBuild-based tasks.

Comment: @keith8041: this will always work, but just be aware of the fact that `[1-999]` means: `one character that can be 1 to 9, or 9 or 9`, which matches only the first character after `Error count: `. I think you rather meant something like: `Error count: [1-9][0-9]*`. Note: I'm just nitpicking here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach I used to catpure build failures from MSDeploy when I ran a Nant script for deployment remotely.  It is not an identical scenerio but should give you a concept to go from.  Basically you can run this from a shell you need a scripting language like powershell to capture the output and than post processes the plain text coming back from msdeploy. I rasied this issue with the MSDeploy team and let them know this was a pain to deal with.

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/12/29/update-on-using-msdeploy-for-remote-deployments.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In TeamCity 9 go to the build configuration and click on the Failure Conditions. Check the checkbox "an error message is logged by build runner". This will fail your build if an error happens during deployment.